# Powergate and IPFS Keeps Failing to Create A Storage Deal

Tags: ipfs

I am using WSL Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10. I installed lotus, ipfs-go, pow, and powd. I waited for the lotus daemon to finish syncing then I launched ipfs with `ipfs daemon`, then the pow daemon in a screen session with `powd --lotustoken <mylotustokenhere>`.

So the lotus daemon is synced and running, the ipfs daemon is running, and the powergate daemon is also running connected to the lotus daemon through the admin auth token. I already staged a directory and got a cid (through powergate) with the command `pow data stage path/to/dir` and got a 'bafy' starting IPFS hash. The directory is about 5GB in size. I created a random data bin file through a dd command. I chose to make it 5GB because I noticed that a lot of miners want you to make the job for more than 4GB. I ran the command `pow config apply --watch <CID> -o -c custom-072321-config.json`. This was my custom-072321-config.json file.

```
{
  "hot":  {
    "enabled":  false,
    "allowUnfreeze":  false,
    "unfreezeMaxPrice":  "0",
    "ipfs":  {
      "addTimeout":  "900"
    }
  },
  "cold":  {
    "enabled":  true,
    "filecoin":  {
      "replicationFactor":  "1",
      "dealMinDuration":  "518400",
      "excludedMiners":  [],
      "trustedMiners":  [],
      "countryCodes":  [],
      "renew":  {
        "enabled":  false,
        "threshold":  "0"
      },
      "address":  "<my filecoin address with 400000000 attoFIL>",
      "maxPrice":  "100000000000",
      "fastRetrieval":  true,
      "dealStartOffset":  "8640",
      "verifiedDeal":  false
    }
  },
  "repairable":  false
}
```

But the job failed... IDK why?

This was my error that I got:

```
                 JOB ID                |             STATUS             | MINER | PRICE | DEAL STATUS
---------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------+-------+--------------
            <my job id here>           | JOB_STATUS_FAILED executing    |       |       |
                                       | cold-storage config: getting   |       |       |
                                       | cid cummulative size:          |       |       |
                                       | getting cid cummulative        |       |       |
                                       | size: calculating data size:   |       |       |
                                       | merkledag: not found           |       |       |
<myusername>@<mycompname>:~$
```

So I removed all of the files from the IPFS daemon pinning system with `ipfs pin ls --type recursive | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 ipfs pin rm` then ran `ipfs repo gc` to make sure that they were garbage collected. I ran `ipfs add -r --pin=false path/to/dir` and got a Q starting CID and ran the command `pow config apply --watch <CID> -o -c custom-072321-config.json` again with the new CID starting with a Q and I got the same error as above. So I figured that the original bafy starting CID and the Q starting CID were still describing the same directory. So I ran the original `pow config apply --watch <CID> -o -c custom-072321-config.json` command with the original `bafy` starting CID and after sticking on JOB_STATUS_EXECUTING for a long time, I got this error:

```
                 JOB ID                |                                                              STATUS                                                              | MINER | PRICE | DEAL STATUS
---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------------
            <my job id here>           | JOB_STATUS_FAILED automatically staging cid: adding data to ipfs: Post                                                           |       |       |    
                                       | "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=%2Fipfs%2F<bafystaringCID>&recursive=true":                                            |       |       |    
                                       | context deadline exceeded                                                                                                        |       |       |
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I store my file on Filecoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I was not able to correct this error without changing the install. What I ended up doing was re-installing powergate but this time doing it through docker instead of installing lotus, ipfs, and powergate separately and trying to link them all together.

Btw, I recommend doing `screen -S newScreen` and running the install commands in the screen shell. That way when you want to check logs through the below mentioned command `docker logs mainnet_*` you can do `Ctrl+a, d` to disconnect from the screen session and run the log checking command in a your original terminal environment. When it's time to go back to the installing commands shell just run `screen -ls` to find the session's name and then run `screen -r <session name here>`.

This was the way that I installed powergate that worked:

1. `git clone https://github.com/textileio/powergate.git`
2. `cd powergate/docker/`
3. `nano docker-compose.yaml`
4. between line 32 and 33, add `command: ["lotus", "daemon", "--import-snapshot", "https://fil-chain-snapshots-fallback.s3.amazonaws.com/mainnet/minimal_finality_stateroots_latest.car"]`
5. `make up`
6. Wait for the blockchain to finish downloading. Check progress with `docker logs mainnet_lotus_1` look for 1.54 GiB / 35.65 GiB, 2.51 GiB / 35.65 GiB, 3.36 GiB / 35.65 GiB...
7. When the blockchain is finished downloading kill the process with ^C and run `make down`
8. `nano docker-compose.yaml`
9. Delete the line that you added.
10. `make up`
11. Wait for the blockchain state syncing to finish. Check progress with `docker logs mainnet_powergate_1` and look for

```
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 370, todo: 191
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 370, todo: 142
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 370, todo: 103
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 370, todo: 54
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 370, todo: 8
<Time And Date>        WARN    lotus-client    lotus/metrics.go:90     Louts behind in syncing with height diff 39, todo: 7
<Time And Date>        INFO    ffs-scheduler   scheduler/scheduler.go:<Number>      running scheduler gc...
<Time And Date>        INFO    ffs-scheduler   scheduler/scheduler.go:<Number>      scheduler gc ran with 0 excluded cids, unpinning 0 staged cids
```

When the syncing is complete you can successfully make Filecoin deals without the `merkledag: not found` error occcuring.

@jsign on Github stated that the error can be fixed without doing a docker re-install be simply referring to "https://docs.textile.io/powergate/faq/#i-see-a-log-error-computing-commp-failed-generating-commp-blockstore-block-not-found-what-does-this-mean."  This is referenced here "https://github.com/textileio/powergate/issues/849."